# how to find all directories with a certain name

Tags: unix

on an unix shell, how can i find all directories with a certain name?

say i have a folder structure like

```
/home/abcd/foo/
/home/abcd/foo/bar
/home/xyz/ab/foo/
/home/none/in/here
```

and i am searching for folders named foo, i would want to return a list like:

```
/home/abcd/foo/
/home/xyz/ab/foo/
```

how could i do this?

thanks

Answer (score 7):

```
find /home -name foo -type d
```

Comment: Which means (as a matter of education): print out the paths of all items beneath the directory /home that both have the name foo and are directories (-type d)

Comment: @tarnoob: You're welcome. You can mark this answer as accepted then.